# Recovering Broken Connections In A Peer to Peer Network

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am implementing a peer to peer network using WCF NetPeerTcpBinding connections.

I am using a central server which itself overrides the class CustomPeerResolverService. All this service does is register peers, and publish information about the peers to each other.

On my server application I can visibly see which peers are currently connected on the GUI.

My question is, each peer has a TCP connection to the server. When I unplug my network connection all connections to this server are severed. When the network comes back online those connections to the server are not re-established. What do I need to do to make sure they are re-established?

Here is what each of the peer to peer bindings look like on the peers.

```
<netPeerTcpBinding>
    <binding name="PeerTcpConfig" port="0">
      <security mode="None"></security>
      <resolver mode="Custom">
        <custom address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1/GlobalStoreAPIServer"  
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpConfig">
        </custom>
      </resolver>
    </binding>
  </netPeerTcpBinding>
```

So what that means is that my server has an endpoint at 'net.tcp://127.0.0.1/GlobalStoreAPIServer'

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/3fd80acd-6fed-4f25-8a36-f13b73a3a95d